# How to read database from an existing table without setup resources

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I need a tutorial to read an existing custom table. I have been searching many tutorial but it looks like we have to create setup / install file first. I just want to read all records from my table, like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

The most confusing part for me is in Magento we have 3 models:

- the model
- the collection model
- the resource model

My table name is `paketid_booking_result`

I want to show it in `adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view`

My table has already some records in it.

I have tried to create :

1. **`class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`**

   ```
   protected function _construct()
   {
       $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result');
   }
   ```
2. **`class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result extends Mage_EAV_Model_Entity_Abstract`**

   ```
   public function __construct()
   {
       $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
       $this->setType('paketid_shipping_result');
       $this->setConnection(
           $resource->getConnection('shipping_read'),
           $resource->getConnection('shipping_write')
       );
   }
   ```
3. **`class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Result extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`**

   ```
   protected function _construct()
   {
       $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result'); //initialized resource model
   }
   ```

Config file `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <PaketId_Shipping>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </PaketId_Shipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <paketid_shipping>
                <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>paketid_shipping_result</resourceModel>
            </paketid_shipping>
            <paketid_shipping_resource>
                <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
            </paketid_shipping_resource>
            <paketid_shipping_resource>
                <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <result>
                        <table>paketid_booking_result</table>
                    </result>
                </entities>
            </paketid_shipping_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <paketid_shipping>
                <class>PaketId_Shipping_Helper</class>
            </paketid_shipping>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <paketid_shipping>
                <class>PaketId_Shipping_Block</class>
            </paketid_shipping>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <shipping_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </shipping_write>
            <shipping_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </shipping_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <paketid_booking>
                    <file>shipping.xml</file>
                </paketid_booking>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <paketid_shipping>
                <active>1</active>
                <sallowspecific>1</sallowspecific>
                <model>paketid_shipping/carrier</model>
                <name>Paket ID Shipping Extension</name>
                <price>10.00</price>
                <title>Paket ID Shipping Extension</title>
            </paketid_shipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

The layout `shipping.xml` :

```
<layout version="1.0">
  <adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="paketid_booking/adminhtml_sales_order_view_info_booking" name="paketid_booking.order.info.booking.block" template="paketid/shipping.phtml" after="order_history" />
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view>
</layout>
```

The template `shipping.phtml` :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('PaketId_Shipping');?>
<?php $booking = Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection();
<?php foreach($bookings as $booking): ?>
<h1><?php echo $booking->getBookingCode() ?></h1>
```

Those script above produce nothing, I mean my query didn't return anything, and my `shipping.phtml` not showing. The existing table `paketid_booking_result` is coming from another extension, I want to show it in admin page for a reason.

I am new in Magento, I really need advice and best practice for my case. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: where is the `shipping.xml` in your `config.xml`

Comment: i've edited my question. I added `layout` after `global` tag

Answer (score 1):

Your `resourceModel` node is not properly declared in your `config.xml`

It should match the node that declares the resource models so instead of:

```
<resourceModel>paketid_shipping_result</resourceModel>
```

You should have:

```
<resourceModel>paketid_booking_resource</resourceModel>
```

Because your resource model declaration is the following:

```
  <paketid_booking_resource>
    <class>PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
      <entities>
        <result>
          <table>paketid_booking_result</table>
        </result>
      </entities>
  </paketid_booking_resource>
```

Comment: thanks for your correction, but my template still not showing, so that I cannot check my query :(